# Javascript bouncing box inside another bouncing box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with bouncing boxes in JavaScript, everything works when there is only one box. But when I add a bouncing box inside the parent box, the child box would behave wild, it doesn't bounce back when reaching the border.

Below is my complete code.

```js
const INIT_VELOCITY = 0.05;



class Box {
  constructor(boxElem) {
    this.box = boxElem;
    this.reset();
  }

  get x() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.box).getPropertyValue("--x"));
  }

  set x(value) {
    this.box.style.setProperty("--x", value);
  }

  get y() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.box).getPropertyValue("--y"));
  }

  set y(value) {
    this.box.style.setProperty("--y", value)
  }

  rect() {
    return this.box.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  reset() {
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
    const angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

    this.direction = {
      x: Math.cos(angle),
      y: Math.sin(angle)
    }
  }

  update(delta, container) {

    this.x += this.direction.x * delta * INIT_VELOCITY;
    this.y += this.direction.y * delta * INIT_VELOCITY;

    if (this.rect().top < container.rect().top || this.rect().bottom > container.rect().bottom) {
      this.direction.y *= -1;
    }

    if (this.rect().left < container.rect().left || this.rect().right > container.rect().right) {
      this.direction.x *= -1;
    }
  }
}

let delta;
let lastTime = 0;

const box0 = new Box(document.querySelector("#box0"));
const box1 = new Box(document.querySelector("#box1"));
const box2 = new Box(document.querySelector("#box2"));

function update(time) {
  delta = time - lastTime;
  lastTime = time;
  box1.update(delta, box0);
  box2.update(delta, box1);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box0 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box1 {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: black;
  top: calc(var(--y)*1vh);
  left: calc(var(--x)*1vw);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

#box2 {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: red;
  top: calc(var(--y)*1vh);
  left: calc(var(--x)*1vw);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="box0"></div>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

When I do not call the update method of box1, the red box2 would work perfectly, bouncing off each time it touches the black box1 border.
The black box1 would always bounce off the border of box0, which is just 100vh and 100vw.

But when I run the code above, the red box2 moves normally within black box1. But it doesn't stop upon reaching the border, and just shakes around in the white area until it comes back inside black box1.

Comment: Quick comment as I don't have time for a proper answer and I don't know if it's everything there is to say, but you inverse the direction when your element is outside of the container but you don't update the current value, so you actually let your box go out of the container. Once it's there if it's out by e.g 2 px and that at the next frame it gone back only by 1px, it will still be at -1px and thus will invert the directions again, making it go even further outside of the parent and do this again and again.

Comment: To fix that, when you see that the box is outside of the container, make it go back inside, the best is even to calculate where it should have been. For instance if it's at coord x: -50 then we can assume it travelled 50px too much on the left and you could place it inside at coord x: +50.

Comment: Why is your HTML structured such that the boxes are not within each other? In the question you mention 'parent' but there are no parents. If you put them inside then at least the red box stays within the black box.

Comment: Haworth, sorry for the informal use of word, what I meant by "parent" was the wrapping box. I shouldn't have called it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaiido's comments explained what my code's problems are.

> Once it's there if it's out by e.g 2 px and that at the next frame it gone back only by 1px, it will still be at -1px and thus will invert the directions again, making it go even further outside of the parent and do this again and again.

I modified my update(delta, container) method this way and it fixed my problem

```
update(delta,container){

        this.x += this.direction.x * delta * INIT_VELOCITY;
        this.y += this.direction.y * delta * INIT_VELOCITY;
        
        if(this.rect().top < container.rect().top){
            //this line reverses direction
            this.direction.y *= -1;
            //the following two lines calculate where the box should have been
            this.y = container.rect().top + this.rect().height / 2;
            this.y = this.y / innerHeight * 100
        }
        
        if(this.rect().bottom > container.rect().bottom){
            this.direction.y *= -1;
            this.y = container.rect().bottom - this.rect().height / 2;
            this.y = this.y / innerHeight * 100
        }
        
        if(this.rect().left < container.rect().left){
            this.direction.x *= -1;
            this.x = container.rect().left + this.rect().width / 2;
            this.x = this.x / innerWidth * 100
        }
        
        if(this.rect().right > container.rect().right){
            this.direction.x *= -1;
            this.x = container.rect().right - this.rect().width / 2;
            this.x = this.x / innerWidth * 100
        }
    }
```